# Calculate track from location points without time

Tags: python, numpy, gps, mapping, traveling-salesman

I've got a bunch of points [ID, lat, lon, time] but the time is unreliable. The time for a couple points is often mixed up and there are some large gaps. I want to be able to calculate a track (basically just a linear-fit or polyfit) from the points but I'm struggling to get them into some kind of order.

First I tried ordering by lat/lon and this works for the cases where the track is moving constantly in one direction. There are all kind of mismatches and problems when the track turns back on itself.

Maybe it's a travelling salesman problem but in this case I don't know where the object's track starts/ends.

I've thought about picking a point at random and travelling to the next closest point and repeat; but how would I complete the track if my random point is in the middle and there are often large gaps between points.

[GPS points, incorrectly placed into tracks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76pNx.png)

Here's a picture of some of the GPS points, colour coded by ID. I've sorted the points by [lat,lon] and you can see the blue track has problems.

This is so simple do do manually, just join the dots, but I can't figure it out computationally. I'm using python/numpy/pandas for this and there are millions of these points so it would be helpful to avoid computationally intensive methods but at this point I'm just plain stuck.

EDIT:
Okay, so this is not so simple. It's probably going to involve writing particle/Kalman filters or maybe some kind of Hamiltonian cost equation and then iterating the whole damn track to get an optimal solution. The best (least work for me) solution would be to try to correct the junk time field and possible build a statistical guesser from the average bearing of point segments.

EDIT + Solution:
Okay, so it's no that complex. The data I'm looking at the objects generally travel N-S or E-W with little deviation. Where there is complex manoeuvring I usually have more reliable time data. The non-general solution for my dataset would be to check whether the track can be defined as a function of latitude (N-S travel with no S-N movement component) else can it be function of longitude. Then order by lat/lon and bam. This won't work in the case of spirals or other complex tracks but those are minimal in my data.

Not the perfect solution but good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, seems like simple clustering - or even sorting with the right metric would do the trick.

#### Your data

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image('https://i.stack.imgur.com/76pNx.png')
```

[image: output_0_0.png]

#### Generate similar data

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
data_lat = np.arange(300, dtype=np.int32) * (1 + (np.random.random(300) - 0.5) * 0.1)
data_lon = np.arange(5, 305, dtype=np.int32) * (1 + (np.random.random(300) - 0.5) * 0.1)
%pylab inline
import seaborn as sns
plt.scatter(data_lat, data_lon)
```

[image: output_3_3.png]

```
import itertools
seq_data = [(la, lo) for i, (la, lo) in enumerate(zip(data_lat, data_lon)) if 
            i in itertools.chain(range(20), range(55, 70), range(120, 165), 
                 range(200, 250), range(280, 300))]

plt.plot(*zip(*seq_data))
plt.scatter(*zip(*seq_data))
```

[image]

#### Scramble

```
import random
random.seed(42)
data = seq_data.copy()
random.shuffle(data)

plt.plot(*zip(*data))
plt.scatter(*zip(*data))
```

[image]

#### Sort

```
data.sort(key=lambda t: (t[0]**2 + t[1]**2)**(1/2))
plt.plot(*zip(*data))
plt.scatter(*zip(*data))
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of using a custom sorting metric. In your case it looks like you're sorting by distance from the origin. In the case of where the direction of travel is more or less perpendicular to the origin there'll be some errors. I also can't consider the first point as the origin since the objects can turn. It'll have to be some kind of sorting algorithm that takes the distance between each of the points to all the other points into account. I don't know.

Comment: True. But the answer may be a starting point for your own data-specific metric. Like: start with start point `s` (no pun intended) to the lower left. Use distance metric above to indentify next five points in line w.r.t. `s`. Now get a new point `s`, i.e. the last point added this way. Iterate. However, you might always have ambiguities if your desired line intersects itself. Unless you fit an appropriate model to the data. Or try a semi-automatic approach by giving additional sampling points in the correct order.

Comment: (You may also use those additional samples as your `s` points.)